# what is the code if I want to say that x is an element of the real number system in LaTeX using notation?

Tags: code

what is the code if I want to say that x is an element of the real number system in LaTeX using notation.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Use `$ x \in \mathbb{R}$` or `$ x \in \mathbf{R}$` (Bourbaki style).

Comment: For `\mathbb{R}` to work, load `unicode-math`, `mathalpha` with an appropriate `bb=` option, or for the most traditional symbols, `amsmath`.